# Can't convert from String to int in Java

Tags: java, type-conversion, date

I'm getting the current time and I want to convert it into Integer, thats what I did , but it keeps giving me `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4:12:31"`

```
            long unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
            Date time=new java.util.Date((long)unixTime*1000);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(time);
            int hours = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minutes = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            int seconds = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);


            int currentTime = (int) Double.parseDouble((hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds));
```

Comment: if string have ":" you cant convert to string, why you want current time in int?

Comment: I need to compare it with two times , like currentTime> 8:00 and currentTime<15:00 , any other way to do it? @Dev_Abraham

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that. If you need to compare times, use LocalTime.

```
    LocalTime b = LocalTime.of(17, 30);//hh,mm,ss

    LocalTime c = LocalTime.parse("20:30:30");//hh:mm:ss

    System.out.println(b.isBefore(c));//true, also there are methods like compareTo, isAfter
```

If you need to compare dates, there is also a class called `LocalDate`. If you need to compare both dates and time, you can use `LocalDateTime`. Comparing those objects is the same, as comparing two `LocalTime` obejcts.

`LocalTime.of` and `.parse` are static factory methods. They are used to create new instances of `LocalTime`. From a user perspective, they work like constructors — you call them and you receive in return an object of its class. More about them and constructors you can read here: [Java Constructors vs Static Factory Methods](https://www.baeldung.com/java-constructors-vs-static-factory-methods).

Comment: Still can't get what LocalTime.of and .parse is for, more explanation please?

Comment: These are static factory methods. They are used to create new instances of LocalTime. From user perspective, they work like constructors- you call them and you receive in return an object of its class. More about them and constructors you can read here https://www.baeldung.com/java-constructors-vs-static-factory-methods

Comment: For getting the current time in your time zone (or some other time zone) as a `LocalTime` use like `LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Curacao"))`.